# docopt not working and proceeding

Tags: python, docopt

The following  version 0.6.2 docopt string is not working although i dont find any error in it:

```
"""Usage:
  somecommand.py [-n nos] [-u] [-c] [-s start]

  Options:

  -h    show help
  -u    some reply
  -n    number to fetch
  -c    ask to do it
  -s    start from?
"""
```

on commandline:

```
somecommand.py -n 2 -s 5

Usage:
  privateunreadlybrate.py [-n nos] [-u] [-c] [-s start]
```

the execution does not proceed and it keeps on showing usage for any command entered.
So where is the error?

Comment: What version of docopt do you use?

Comment: version 0.6.2 docopt @KRUKUSA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'nos' value also has to be given in the 'options:' part, try this:

```
"""Usage:
  somecommand.py [-n nos] [-u] [-c] [-s start]

  Options:

  -h        show help
  -u        some reply
  -n nos    number to fetch
  -c        ask to do it
  -s start  start from?
"""
```